# Pandas DataFrame column to cell in pivot table

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks something like the following:

```
   | A | B | C | D
---+---+---+---+---
 1 | a | c | e | g
---+---+---+---+---
 2 | a | c | e | h
---+---+---+---+---
 3 | b | d | f | i
```

And I'm looking to get a pivot table out of this with A in the columns and B in the rows, then C and D as sets, as below:

```
   |     a     |    b
---+-----------+--------
 c | (e, h, i) |   ()
---+-----------+--------
 d |    ()     | (f, i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
>>> f = lambda obj: set(obj[['C', 'D']].values.ravel())
>>> df.groupby(['B', 'A']).apply(f).unstack()
A               a            b
B                             
c  set([g, e, h])          NaN
d             NaN  set([i, f])
```

or, you can have a tuple of unique elements instead of set object:

```
>>> f = lambda obj: tuple(np.unique(obj[['C', 'D']].values))
>>> df.groupby(['B', 'A']).apply(f).unstack()
A          a       b
B                   
c  (e, g, h)     NaN
d        NaN  (f, i)
```